# IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array (Gson Java)

Tags: java, json, gson, spotify

I've been trying to create using Gson a way to import track data. This is my first attempt at using Gson and I am struggling to understand where I am going wrong. I am trying to use spotify's json. This is the address I am using.
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=%22Perform%20this%20way%22&type=track
And I've created a class to import it. I have been following this guide.
http://www.javabeat.net/invoking-restful-web-service-using-api-in-java-net-and-gson/

I get the following error after typing in my query and giving it the okay to go ahead..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
    at TestingNonApplication.GsonTesting.main2(GsonTesting.java:72)
```

- Refers to this line. *JsonArray jArray = rootElement.getAsJsonArray();*

Is there anything I've left out. I wasn't sure if I needed a toString or serialization.

```
  package TestingNonApplication;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Scorchgid
 */
public class GsonTesting {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    String baseURLStart = "http://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=\"";
    String baseURLEnd = "\"&type=track";
    String jsonSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GsonTesting gTest = new GsonTesting();
            gTest.main2();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GsonTesting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GsonTesting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void main2() throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        Scanner commandlineReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchString = "";
        boolean contin = false;
        while (contin == false) {
            System.out.println("Enter query");
            String query = commandlineReader.nextLine();
            searchString = baseURLStart + query + baseURLEnd;
            searchString = searchString.replace(" ", "%20");
            System.out.println(searchString
                    + "\r\n Type Yes to continue or anything else to re enter");
            query = commandlineReader.nextLine();
            if (query.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                contin = true;
            }
        }
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        /* Connection and Response */
        URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(searchString).openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement rootElement = jsonParser.parse(reader);
        JsonArray jArray = rootElement.getAsJsonArray();

        List results = new ArrayList();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        for (JsonElement spotifyElement : jArray) {
            Tracks spot = gson.fromJson(rootElement, Tracks.class);
            results.add(spot);
            System.out.println(spot.toString());
        }
    }
}

class Tracks {

    String href;
    List<Items> items;

    public class Items {

        Album albums;

        public class Album {

            String album_type;
            String[] available_markets;
            External_Urls external_urls;

            public class External_Urls {

                String spotify;
            }
            String href;
            String id;
            List<Image> images;

            public class Image {

                Integer height;
                String url;
                Integer width;
            }
            String name;
            String type;
            String uri;
            List<Artists> artists;
        }

        List<Artists> artist;

        public class Artists {

            External_Urls external_urls;

            public class External_Urls {

                String spotify;
            }

            String herf;
            String id;
            String name;
            String type;
            String uri;
        }

        String avaliable_markets;
        Integer disc_number;
        Integer duration;
        Boolean explicity;
        External_Urls external_ids;

        public class External_Ids {

            String isrc;
        }
        External_Urls external_urls;

        public class External_Urls {

            String spotify;
        }
        String herf;
        String id;
        String name;
        Integer popularity;
        String preview_url;
        Integer tracknumber;
        String type;
        String uri;

    }

    Integer limit;
    String next;
    Integer offset;
    String previous;
    Integer total;
}
```

Comment: How is "this is not a JSON array" not clear enough as a message? Or do you, by any chance, not understand the difference between a JSON _object_ and a JSON _array_? Please refer to RFC 7159

Comment: What's not a JSON array. the Link I am passing it? the code which I have set out? and to answer your question. I thought I did but I guess I do not. Has the guide I used lead me to any incorrect assumptions?

Comment: That's what I say. I clicked the link. It is a JSON _OBJECT_. Please go read RFC 7159 and http://json.org

Answer (score 1):

Json string is perfect.

There are 4 mistakes in your class to map json to obj. (class Tracks)

1. external_urls should be an object, not list (at all three places)
2. artists list should be outside album class.
3. external_ids should be object, not list (at one place)
4. spotify member is missing in one external_urls class.

A general advise is to reduce the use of inner classes when using gson (convert your inner classes to normal public classes and create the object instead of the inner class). 
Also more readable and reusable code in this case. For example, if you design your external_urls as a separate class you just need one class and can have 3 member obj instead of the 3 inner classes you have now. Gson will work perfectly if you do so.

Comment: To confirm external_urls should be an object of type External_Urls? Does that mean I change the other lists if so why not? (Trying to learn)

Comment: Also I've changed it as you've suggested. Thank you first for your help but I'm still having the same issue.